# ASP.Net Master Pages and Contents

Tags: asp.net

I have tried my best to solve this but i cannot figure this out. Please could you assist me:

I have a master page with 3 containers:

I created my own Login page as a start page and then it redirects after successfull login to Default.aspx wich is a web content form with master as its master page. In default i have my cphHeader container that displays user info and a menu. Now i want to display something else in container 3 cphMain.. So i have created another page called store info and i have done all the code behind i had too. how do i display this page in container 3 and also how do i load it up as part of what the user see after login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would normally create 3 seperate content sections in the same page, not 3 pages for one page.

You have to think of this as the content being the "page" not the master.  Does it make sense to have 3 pages when a user wants to see one?  For example, you would have a single page that has these content sections.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="BannerContent" runat="server">
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeaderContent" runat="server">
    <h2>Section 3</h2>
</asp:Content>
```

Now, it's possible to create seperate "pages", for code re-use reasons, and typically you would treat them as user controls rather than pages themselves.

Comment: Thank you. I got used to using frames a long time ago and now with ASP.Net i was thinking in the same mindset but i grasp it now.